# Why cant nail polish be used as an acid mask for making a PCB?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

In the question: [PCB etching with sodium persulfate](http://My%20PCBs%20etch%20all%20bad!%20(sodium%20persulfate)), permanent markers seem the most used and experimented with. The thickness of nail polish would give more solid planes and traces.

Might nail polishes resist most common copper etchants mentioned such as:

- Sodium Persulphate
- Ferric Chloride
- Peroxide + Vinegar + Salt

sufficiently for etching a PCB?

Comment: Chemistry is an experimental science. Part of the problem would be with removing the nail polish which takes a very reactive solvent. So try experimenting....

Comment: Nail polish works well with nitric acid and removal is done quite easily with acetone. Not sure it helps but the experiment is really easy.  Just try on some copper of no interest.